# DRF extract code from [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.', code='blank')]

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I would like to extract 'code' from Error Detail.

I got ErrorDetail from this code.

```
def get_error_message(serializer):
    default_errors = serializer.errors
    message = {}
    for field_name, field_errors in default_errors.items():
        error = [field_error[:] for field_error in field_errors]
        message[field_name] = field_errors[0]
    return message
```

When I print the `error`, it looks like this.

```
[ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.', code='blank')]
```

I could find methods about extracting 'string', but not the 'code'.

I have tried `field_errors[1]` to get 'code', but it just raised Index Error.

Answer (score 0):

you can extract string and code using:

```
title = field_error.title()
code = field_error.code
```